# Adding dynamic security group members to shared mailbox permissions script

Tags: azure, powershell, permissions, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

Trying to do something like this to add members of an azure dynamic security group to the shared mailbox they belong to based on CSV info

```
Import-Csv C:\users\jeiger\desktop\kiosknames.csv | ForEach-Object {

foreach ($kioskgroup in $_.kioskgroupname){
    foreach ($user in $kioskgroup){
        Add-MailboxPermission $_.kioskemail -User $user -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $false
        Add-RecipientPermission $_.kioskemail -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $user
    }
}

}
```

Headers would read something like:
kioskgroupname and kioskemail

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Well, what happened when you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the [Azure AD Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#installing-the-azure-ad-module) and [EXO V2 module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-the-exo-v2-module).

Refer to this script:

```
$username = "{username of admin}"
$password = "{password of admin}"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secureStringPwd
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential

$DynamicAADGroupMembers = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "{object id of the azure dynamic security group}"

Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credential

$sharedMailbox = "{email address of the shared mailbox}"

foreach ($user in $DynamicAADGroupMembers){
    Add-MailboxPermission $sharedMailbox -User $user.ObjectId -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $false
    Add-RecipientPermission $sharedMailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $user.ObjectId
}
```